# Can Reverse Flash time travel?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In the 1st season of *The Flash* we see that Thawne is faster than Flash. Then why did he need Barry to time travel to his to open the portal, why didn't he run fast?

Comment: He was unable to tap into speed force at that moment.

Answer (score 3):

On the advices of [Ankit Sharma](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1190/ankit-sharma) and [KutuluMike](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/1146/kutulumike), I'm jotting down my comment here:

Though Thawne could run faster than Barry, he never had the full grasp on speed-force. Eventually, he lost the connection with speed-force just after killing Nora. That's why he had to re-create the particle accelerator explosion to give Barry the speed so that he might help him go back to his time. However, he could charge up himself with tachyon pulse generator; but that's another point.

But the crux is that Thawne could time-travel but for some reasons he lost his connection with speed-force.

Answer (score 0):

The comics give a better explanation during the Flashpoint crossover event (which is what season 1 of Flash was VERY loosely based on).

> At the point where Thawne had killed Nora, Barry's life changed enough that he wouldn't become the Flash.  The comics show that Barry doesn't just tap into the Speed Force, he actually generates it across time and space with every step that he runs.  This hasn't been explained in the show yet.  Thawne couldn't access it because it never existed, hence his need to become Wells, cause the particle accelerator explosion much sooner than originally it would happen, and train Barry up for max speed, to generate a speed force that was accessible even in the future where he was from.

Strongly recommend the Flashpoint crossover; you'll find a lot of background information that explains quite a lot (if you squint at it sideways a little anyway)

Comment: Hey, anyone know why you have to move your mouse over the yellow text box in order to see the content? This is the second time I've seen this on the Movies exchange. Thanks!

Comment: Because it's potentially spoilerish content - people might not want to know, usually used for new movie discussions and the like, but anything plot-ish can be hidden with a couple characters in the text :)

Comment: to be fair: they haven't explained this in the show yet because I'm pretty sure it's not *true* in the show.

Comment: Thanks, Dave! What characters does one use?

Comment: Use a > followed by a ! before your text.  Think it only works in answers rather than comments though?

Comment: @KutuluMike that remains to be defined I guess.  I just thought it was a potential explanation that made a great deal of sense so submitted it.  If it turns out to be incorrect, fair enough :)

Comment: This is wrong. Given that adult Barry was there, and told young Barry not to save Nora, nothing really changed. It was supposed to happen. And what makes you think this is ***anything like Flashpoint***?

Comment: @cde There are a few similarities; specifically covering that the death of Barry's mother was Thawne's fault, thus causing Barry to go back and try to fix it.  In the comics this caused the Flashpoint event to happen; in the tv show, the version of Barry who came back to save his mother was warned off by the older version of himself (speculatively, because that version knew what would happen if he was allowed to?).  Flashpoint also introduced the DC's New 52 multiverse, which is effectively what happened at the end of season 1 (52 breaches, lots of references to 52 all over the show)...

Comment: Regardless of the connection to Flashpoint or not, I believe that the point regarding Barry/the speed force and Thawne is correct in terms of explaining why he couldn't access the speed force.  It does however rely on knowledge from outside the tv universe which may or may not be included later...